# Should the [auto] tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, clean-up

I came across the [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) tag today and at first glance had no idea what it should apply to. Then I read the description which in turn made me question whether the tag should be renamed to something more descriptive as it seems the tag name is a bit ambiguous. The current description for [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) is:

> The `auto` keyword was repurposed in C++11 for a deduced type. When
>   used to replace a type name in an initialized variable declaration,
>   the variable is given the same type as the initializer. When used as a
>   return type, the return type is specified as a trailing return type,
>   or deduced from the return-expression.

Looking at the ~1000 questions [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) is being used on, apparently many users also have no idea what it's intended for. [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) is currently being used on everything from Java, JavaScript, and CSS to PHP, WordPress, HTML and Swift. And C++. So, pretty much anything.

Should the tag be renamed to something more descriptive, possibly more C++ centric? What should be done with the hundreds of questions that are currently tagged with [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) that don't have anything to do with C++?

Comment: Well, if you disregard posts where `auto` is just a filler-word, and generally all off-topic posts, are there still many non-C++ posts left?

Comment: [Doesn't really look like it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bauto%5d%20-%5b*c%2b%2b*%5d%20is%3aq)

Comment: @Deduplicator ~33% isn't many?

Comment: May I be the first to suggest renaming this post `Should [auto] be resprayed or scrapped`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Should it be repossessed?

Comment: @Pekka Probably not `[driven out of town]`...

Comment: @ZevSpitz: That's like a double pun. I'm not sure that's even legal!

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sorry; I'm driven and I can't resist...

Comment: [auto]: more than meets the eye?

Answer (score 15):

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/popular?show=alltime&sort=votes&tags=auto%20c%2b%2b&mode=all) valid questions involving the `auto` keyword.  I'm not sure burnination is appropriate here.  At the same time, I don't love these specific-feature-of-language-X-that-also-exists-by-other-names-in-other-languages tags.  I mean, it's OK for one tag to be a subset of another, but in that case, we typically want the smaller tag to involve issues which are specific to the larger tag (e.g. questions in [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) cannot be reformulated to lose their [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) nature without also losing their [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) nature).  That's just not true in this case; you can easily reformulate an [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) question into C# or another language with type inference, and the only significant change is renaming `auto` to `var` or some other keyword.  Unless there's some specific feature of C++'s `auto` which doesn't exist in any other language?

**Detag everything not related to C++, then synonymize it with [type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-inference).**

Comment: The link in your question is 404.

Comment: @j08691: Works for me, but not on the mobile site.  Someone go raise a bug on [meta.se].

Comment: I'm on the desktop site.

Comment: @j08691: [¯\\_(ツ)_/¯](http://imgur.com/BeErfq3).

Comment: That's an artifact of how broken the new-nav, and especially it's handling for users not using it is.

Comment: "Unless there's some specific feature" often it's not about the feature, but about the limitations. Can auto be used as a return type of a recursive function? If you have typedef that is actually a pointer, can you use that to initialise auto or do you need to do auto*? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Removed the JS reference.

Comment: For those not on the new nav: [Here's an equivalent link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20auto?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 13):

There is yet another issue here, and that is that the `auto` keyword also exists in C, but with a different meaning. It has the same meaning as in legacy C++ code: declare a variable with automatic storage duration.

The `auto` keyword is rarely ever used in C nor in pre-C++11, yet sometimes it does pop up. I answered a [C question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020791/cant-we-initiate-automatic-array-variables) regarding this just a few days back. It would have been perfectly on-topic to tag that question [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto), even though it has nothing to do with C++11.

I think the proper tag wiki needs to explain the use of the `auto` keyword in C and earlier C++ standards, in addition to the C++11 use.

---

The name [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) can easily be confused with a lot of other things though. Surely there are lots of "automatic things" wherever there is software. Just in C++, I could imagine that several would incorrectly tag questions [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer) instead of [auto-ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-ptr).

Perhaps it would be best to burn [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto) entirely and replace it with [auto-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-keyword).

Comment: If someone uses the `auto` keyword in a C program, they deserve to be mercilessly harrassed until they remove it, and the tag from their question.  I don't think I've ever seen a piece of serious C code that used `auto`. (Heck, even when types were optional, so `auto motive;` meant the same as `int motive;`, the version using `auto` was longer so serious programmers never typed it).  Although your observation about C is valid, it is essentially spurious, but 'tis weird that you got that question with `auto` in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If something, anything, exists in a programming language, then there are always some stupid people who 1) will use it just because they can, and 2) will insist that it is good practice because it compiles.